# How to use a custom class in Laravel when it is in a sub-folder?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

In my new laravel app I've added two custom classes.  One loads fine when I use it in the controller, but the other, which is in another folder, does not work.

The working class, which I will call `Working` is located in `app\Classes`, it has the namespace `namespace App\Classes` and in the controller I call it with `use App\Classes\Working`.

The non-working class, which I will call `NonWorking` is located in `app\Classes\NonWorking`.  I've tried giving it the namespaces `namespace App\Classes` and `namespace App\Classes\NonWorking`.  From the controller I've tried calling it with `use App\Classes\NonWorking` and `use App\Classes\NonWorking\NonWorking`, but I get the error `Class 'App\Classes\NonWorking' not found` or `Class 'App\Classes\NonWorking\NonWorking' not found`.

I've been able to get it to run correctly by moving the NonWorking class into the same folder as the Working class and setting the namespace as `namespace App\Classes`, but the NonWorking class is from another repo and should be in its own folder as it will not be the only one from another repo.

So, how do I get Laravel to understand where this class is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses the [PSR-4 autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). What it means is basically your class should follow the folder structure.

So if you have classes in `app/Classes`, they should have the namespace `App\Classes`.

So the file `app/Classes/Working.php` will have at its top `namespace App\Classes;` and to import it in another file, you write in the other file `use App\Classes\Working;`

If you have a class  inside `app/Classes/SubFolder`, it should have the namespace `namespace App\Classes\SubFolder;`
So here is a class `AmazingClass` in `app/Classes/SubFolder/AmazingClass.php` file:

```
// app/Classes/SubFolder/AmazingClass.php

namespace App\Classes\SubFolder;

class AmazingClass
{
    //
}
```

Let's use `AmazingClass` in another class.

```
// Some file in another namespace

namespace App\My\Random;

use App\Classes\SubFolder\AmazingClass;

// Rest of the file
```

---

Plus: Whenever you add a new class and you can't use it, it's likely that it's not autoloaded. Run the command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to re-autoload the classes.

Answer (score 1):

to solve your issue just create your folders and classes in App folder and run command :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and they load all classes you have created