# Laravel Factory and Model relation when models have specific path

Tags: laravel, namespaces, composer-php, directory-structure, psr-4

I have a project where laravel was migrated from 7 to 9 version

Models are stored in

`app/v2/`

folder

Factories are stored in

`database/factories/v2`

folder

In my composer I have

```
"psr-4": {
    "MyApi\\": "app/",
    "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/"
    ...
}
```

My example model

```
namespace MyApi\v2;

class Test extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
```

has example factory

```
namespace Database\Factories\v2;

use MyApi\v2\Test;

class TestFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Test::class;
```

With this setup everything works good.

But tell me please - is it any way to make it works without adding

`protected $model`

part in factory? Now if I remove it I am getting

`Error: Class "MyApi\Test" not found`

If I move model to "app/" folder and factory to "database/factories" folder everything works well without `protected $model` part in factory.
But I need models be stored in "app/v2" folder.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473364/how-to-use-a-custom-class-in-laravel-when-it-is-in-a-sub-folder